# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n}/n^p$ for $p>1/2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\langle a_n \rangle$ be a sequence of positive numbers.
If $p>1/2$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then how can I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n}/n^p$ also converges? It seems that any kind of convergence test does not work.

Also, does the converse hold? I think it doesn't, but I have trouble finding a counterexample.

Comment: hint for the first: you have a geometric mean there.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus Thank you! I solved for the 1st case. Also, I found all of the counterexamples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** *(substantial)*

- For the first, use the [AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):
  $$
  \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}} \leq \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}
  $$
  and comparison theorems.
- For the second, use the [Cauchy—Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)* on the partial sums:
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{2p}}}
  $$
  then the fact that $p>\frac{1}{2}$ and and comparison theorems.

For the counterexamples, you may want to find sequences such that

- first: $a_{2n}$ is always "big," yet $a_{2n+1}$ is really "small."
- second: for $p=1$, $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} = \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$ (recall that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$ is a convergent series)

> $\ast$ As mentioned in a comment below by [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r), the AM–GM inequality would do as well for the second (and Cauchy–Schwarz for the first), but it's good to know several tools.

Comment: AM-GM should work in the second case as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it! Also, I already found counterexamples of the converse.

Comment: @bellcircle I edited to give clues for counterexamples as well.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, but knowing how to use both the AM-GM and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities is better than having just one feather to one's cap.